# How to twist a cloth?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision, photorealism

I am starting to get pretty stressed and sad. This is for a mobile game I have accepted a project for and if can't solve this I might have to drop this project which will cost me a bit. So if you could help me it will mean a TON! :)

I am trying to make a cloth look like this.
[image]

What I did is I created a cloth simulation with enough vertices and required cloth settings.
Then followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Y2g0I_X_hQ&t=534s) to parent some vertices to a bone. To make it work I had to add the bone to the pin group. I animated the bone to rotate so it will mimic the pinch and rotate movement you will do in real life.

After that with some objects with a collision component I have restricted the movement above so it wouldn't clump up and also used a cylinder in the center.

I tried using some vortex force fields but I didn't do that much. Or I don't know how to use them.

**You can check this [video](https://vimeo.com/389332178) to see how far I got with the simulation.**

If you want to try yourself you can download the [.blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cblq9daat21e2z/Twist-Simulation.blend?dl=0).
*To note that both quality settings are set to 100 so it will take a while to bake.*

**Update**: I made some progress but not enough. Using some wind to push the cloth up and more bones. The bones are animated from the edge of the cloth to a small circle in the middle, but there is a lot of loose cloth remaining on the edges. You can watch this [video](https://vimeo.com/390268557) to see.

Thank you :)

Comment: What you've achieved is pretty good. Could you be more specific about the improvements you're expecting? Also, is it finally to have an animation or a single image (like if the reference picture) but more photorealistic?

Comment: Have you seen this addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNXBYI-WPU4 ? Its interactive, but not for animations, it creates shapekey, so could helps in final shape touch?

Comment: @lemon Thank you, I am trying to animate the T-Shirt transforming from a flat T-Shirt to a twisted version of it like in the image. It is for a game I am making and I will need to do a lot of simmilar cloth simulations.

Comment: @vklidu Today I am pretty sick so I will have to look more into it in the coming days. I have checked the video you sent me and the guy said he is making again the addon from scartch, I checked the new video he posted 4 days ago and it looks very promising. What I will try to do is simulate the cloth the best I can..convert the simulation into keys with the .mdd addon and then as the final frame add the improved version using the addon you suggested. Or can I just add 2 shapekeys? One with the flat T-Shirt and the other one with the final manipulated cloth?

Comment: @Vlad Ilisan: Dont worry take a time :) I will try to extend my A so we can delete comments here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not serious answer, but easier to explaine. What about to add one collision object?

Example with only one bone (your blend) plus Cylinder as collider, bad timing and probably better to use some less circle shape, but you got idea.

[image]

[image]

For final shape you can try [Modeling Cloth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoGjmIVN_68) addon, you can "model" shape in a realtime, final shape is stored as shapekey. So no way to just do animation with two shapekeys O-1, the transition wouldn't work for you.

You can try some combination of your baked cloth sim + shapekey from this addon, somehow ... export to MMD, assign to a mesh via Mesh Cache works, than I wanted to use Surface Deform modifier after that (for target object shaped in state of end of simulation with adjustments as shapekey), but they doesn't run together.

It's really hard to understand how ideal result should looks like :)

Comment: Sort of works what you did here. I will try and experment with this tomorrow and come back with more info on how did it go. :) Thank you!

Comment: I just saw that you were the guy suggesting the cloth addon. Mabye I can merge my solution + this answer's solution + the addon and a shape key to get a nice result. I am curious to try it.

Comment: just a suggestion: scaling down a little more the cylinder and add a solidify modifier between cloth and subdiv. Also try to move the spining bone a little to add some more randomness to the final result.

Comment: @vklidu: i am really curious....how long did your bake take? +1