# Creating silk sheen effect with gold

Tags: materials

I would love to reproduce this golden silk effect [image]

on the material below [image]

[image]

Is this just lighting? or am I able to create this silk effect where the gold is very reflective?

Comment: First of all I would suggest to use a mask to set the golden parts to metallic, like violet = black = 0, and gold = white = 1. The other thing is, maybe you can use this mask for the _Sheen_ (and _Sheen Tint_?) setting in the Principled BSDF as well, maybe not with 0 and 1 but some values inbetween.

Answer (score 6):

*To the gold part ... based on @GordonBrinkmann's comment*

- Use Colorramp or any other node to get contrast BW mask result to separate yellow color to be used as factor for Metalic input. Like here is mask based on image Luminance.

[image]

Or you can create more complex material based on two shaders mixed together with the same mask inside one material.

For twisted cloth try to check [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165903/how-to-twist-a-cloth/166379#166379).

[image]

Comment: Great advice thank you!!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

vklidu just posted a good answer. As an addition, here is a more complex example.

It just uses the *Principled BSDF* but fakes the missing maps for *Roughness* and *Normal* from the diffuse map. And it uses a bit more sheen. If you have these maps use them.

You can enter values greater than 1 for the *Sheen* slot of the *Principled BSDF*. This is useful for fabrics like silk, satin, and velvet.

If you adjust the base color of your texture a bit you can get a result that is very close to the reference image. Note that the color settings depend on the light and can look different.

[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: Thanks this has really helped as changes to the material seemed to affect the physics of the cloth as it fell, this approach seemed to overcome that. (as did upgrading to 2.93.1 ;-)