# Model/Simulate cloth gripped by a hand

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, cloth-simulation

How could I model/simulate this kind of drapery in Blender:

[image]

Or even better (harder?), with twisted motion:

[image]

I have the hand's model, but I don't know how to put the cloth in the hand and make it look  gripped.

Comment: Are you looking for a still image or an animation? I've seen a question about twisted cloth recently ... here it is: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165903/how-to-twist-a-cloth/166379#166379