# Animated cloth swirl

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create an animated swirl of fabric, it can start a little swirled already, but needs to turn and collide with itself. I've tried using force fields such as a negative force to draw it in and a vortex to swirl, but can't quite get it working. Would adding bones be a better solution?

[image]

Comment: I remember a similar question... Yes, here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165903/107598 Does this help?

Comment: @Blunder don't you think that answer is not well explained?

Comment: @Emir *(uh, a question with double negation. Well, the answer is ....yes?)* ... yes, I think the answer is well explained and I hope it helps.

Comment: @Blunder sorry, English is not my best

Comment: @Emir oh, don't worry it's fine. But why did you ask? I got distracted, so I just wrote my comment and didn't mark the question as a duplicate.... if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: Thanks @Blunder that previous post is very helpful. I had tried searching the post for it, but didn't find that - there are quite a few twisting cloth tutorials, but fewer swirling ones.